# highest value that is less than 0 in a list that has mix of negative and positive values

Tags: python, list

I have a list with the these values.

```
lst1 = [1,-2,-4,-8,-9,-12,0,39,12,-3,-7]
```

I need to get the max value that is less than zero.

If I do `print max(last)`- I get 39 and what I need is -2.

`print max(p < 0 for p in lst1)`, I get True and not -2

Answer (score 14):

Never mind, I figured out and it should be

```
print max(p for p in lst1 if p < 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

just filter the list first:

```
max(filter(lambda x:x<0,ls))
```

Comment: Why use `filter` with a `lambda` when you can simply use a generator expression within `max`!

Comment: @Kasramvd because it best demonstrates the concept of filtering which is what OP was missing, performance was not part of the question

Comment: @yurib aren't comprehensions preferred for filtering?